# Power series for functions that have $e$ as a root

Tags: power-series, transcendental-numbers

Define an 'algebraic sympathizer' as any transcendental number that is root of at least one function that when expressed as a power series, each of the coefficients are rational. That is, for all $n$ we have $a_n\in\Bbb{Q}$ and express the function:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
Example: $\pi$ is a sympathizer. Because for $f(x)=\sin(x)$, the rational coefficients $a_n$ are easily generated:
$$a_n = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if $n$ is even} \cr
\frac{1}{n!}(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}},&\text{if $n$ is odd} \end{cases}$$
Is $e$ a sympathizer? Are all computable numbers sympathizers?

Comment: Is $e\pi$ an algebraic sympathizer?

Answer (score 4):

This is more of an extended comment that got too long.

This problem is a bit ambiguous as it is easy to prove that given any real numbers $b_0, b_1,\dotsc,b_n,\dotsc$ such that infinitely many of them are non zero (hence all are non zero by renumbering) you can find non zero rational numbers $a_k$ such that $\sum a_kb_k=0$ (the series converges with value zero).

This is done by induction constructing $a_0,\dotsc,a_n$ such that $$|s_n|=\left|\sum_{k \le n}a_kb_k\right| \le 1/n^2$$ and then picking $a_{n+1}$ rational and non zero so that $a_{n+1}b_{n+1}$ is close enough to $s_n$ and with the right sign so $|s_{n+1}| \le 1/(n+1)^2$ which can be done by approximating $-s_n/b_{n+1}$ close enough by a non-zero rational (here we need of course that $b_n \ne 0$ for all $n$).

In particular, there are such $a_k$ such that $\sum a_kc^k=0$ for any real non-zero $c$ and of course the power series $\sum a_nz^n$ converges for $|z|<c$ and at $z=c$ by construction.

The better question in my opinion is if there is an entire function with the required property, or at least if there is a power series with radius of convergence strictly larger than $|c|$.

Comment: Well, just get a bit greedier and replace $1/n^2$ with $1/n!$ :-)

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that, by the original definition, all real numbers are "algebraic sympathizers".  Is that correct?  If we adopt one of your stricter definitions (that the radius of convergence must be (1) infinite or (2) larger than the root in question), do we get a non-trivial answer?  Do the resulting "strong sympathizers" coincide with, say, real numbers with a finite irrationality measure?