Power series where the number $e$ is a root
I have been going at this question for weeks now and couldn't find anything.
Can we have a series of the form:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$
where $a_n$ are rationals and not all $0$ such that $f(e)=0$?
Just like how $\pi$ is a root of the power series of $\sin(x)$ function:
$$\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
And we know that $\sin(\pi)=0$
My next question is can we prove or disprove the existence of such series given how transcendental numbers are uncountable but these power series are countable, because the coefficients are rational, which means there exist transcendental numbers that can't be the root of a power series.
Is $e$ one of them??
Can we prove or disprove that??

There are uncountably many sequences of rationals.  Indeed, every real number can be thought of as a sequence of rationals (using the truncated decimals as approximations).

"these power series are countable ,because the coefficients are rational": no. $|\Bbb Q^{\Bbb N}|= |{0,1}^{\Bbb N}|=   |\Bbb R|$.

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0\cdot e^n = 0$

There is even continuum many sequences $(a_0, a_1, ...)$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n e^n = 0$, for we can fix any $a_{2n}\in [-\frac{e^{2n}}{4^{2n}}, \frac{e^{2n}}{4^{2n}}]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and pick $a_{2n+1}$ for it to sum to $0$.

@Jakobian that won't give you a rational $a_{2k+1}$

@jjagmath are you reading what I wrote in bad faith, understanding that I've only picked one $n$ for which I choose $a_{2n+1}$?

It is possible to construct the nonzero sequence $a_n$ recursively so that the partial sums are positive and bounded  above by $2^{-n}.$

@Jakobian I'm trying to understand your comment. I don't see how your construction works.

Possibly using the series for $\ln(1-x)$.

@jjagmath I'm simply saying to, given $a_{2n}$ already, to pick $a_1, a_3, a_5, ...$ reccursively as to approximate the sum so that $\sum a_{2n}e^{2n} + \sum a_{2n+1}e^{2n+1} = 0$. Also I've noticed that I should have picked $|a_{2n}|\leq \frac{1}{2^ne^{2n}}$. My bad. Either way this gives you continuum such sequences

@martycohen May be, but some non-trivial adjustments need to be done

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4643919/power-series-for-functions-that-have-e-as-a-root

Every real number can be the root of a power series with rational coefficients. Any one of the proofs in the answers will suffice. Important distinction: "the set of all sequences of rational numbers that is eventually identically zero" is countable, but "the set of all sequences of rational numbers that converge to zero" is uncountable.

You can use a series for $W(e^{1+z})$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function. See wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem):
$W(e^{1+z}) = 1 + \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z^2}{16} + \cdots$
a series which converges on a wide range, but in particular when $z = e$. We have that $W(e^{1+e}) = W(e\cdot e^e) = e$. In the cited paper (Corless, Robert M.; Jeffrey, David J.; Knuth, Donald E. (July 1997). "A sequence of series for the Lambert W function". Proceedings of the 1997 international symposium on Symbolic and algebraic computation. pp. 197–204.) A recurrence relation is given for the coefficients, which proves rationality.
Consequently
$W(e^{1+z}) -z = 1 - \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z^2}{16} + \cdots$
Is a series with the desired behavior.

Assume $a_0=1/2$ and $a_k\neq 0,$ $0\le k\le n-1,$ are chosen so that $0<S_k<{1\over (k+1)!}$ for $0\le k\le n-1.$ There exists a nonzero negative rational $a_{n}$ satisfying $$0<S_{n}:=S_{n-1}+ a_{n}e^{n}<{1\over (n+1)!}$$ By construction $0<S_n<{1\over (n+1)!},$ hence $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^n=\lim S_n=0.$ Moreover $$0<-a_ne^n<S_{n-1}<{1\over n!}$$ Hence  $ |a_n|<{1\over e^nn!}$ which implies that the radius of convergence of $\sum a_nx^n$  is infinite.
Remark The same proof is valid when the number $e$ is replaced by any number $a>0.$

Let $\alpha > 1$ be any real umber. Then by invoking the density of the rational numbers, we can choose $a_1, a_2, \ldots \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ such that
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{n!} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \alpha^k < 1 $$
for all $n$. Moreover, if we write $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \alpha^k$, then
\begin{align*}
1 - \frac{1}{n!} \leq S_{n-1} + a_n\alpha^n < 1
&\implies 0 < a_n\alpha^n < 1 - S_{n-1} \\
&\implies 0 < a_n < \frac{1}{(n-1)! \alpha^n}.
\end{align*}
Finally, set $a_0 = -1$. Then

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k$ has infinite radius of convergence, and

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k \alpha^k = -1 + \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = 0$.


This proves the existence of such a power series.
Perhaps a more intriguing question will be whether if we can find a kind of "natural" power series $f(x)$ with $f(e) = 0$, which I don't have a good idea yet.

Define a sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,...$ of rational numbers recursively by
\begin{align*}
a_0&\,=\;1
\\[4pt]
a_{n+1}&\,=\;
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}&\text{if}\;s_n > 0\\[3pt]
\;\;\;\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}&\text{if}\;s_n < 0\\[3pt]
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_ke^k$.

Then by an easy induction we get that
$
|s_n|\le \bigl({\large{\frac{e}{3}}}\bigr)^n
$
holds for all $n$,$\;$hence $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_ke^k=0$.

As $e=(1/e)^{(1/e)^{(1/e)^{...}}}  $and  $e^{ze^{ze^{ze^{\text{...}} }}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(n+1)^{n-1} z^n}{n!},
$
having $ {z}=$ $\frac{1}{e}$;
will make
$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(n+1)^{n-1} z^n}{n!}-\frac{1}{n!}=0;
$
